# Adding up values in a 2D array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have a numpy  2D array as follows

```
gona = array([['a1', 3], ['a2', 5], ['a3', 1], ['a3', 2], ['a3', 1], ['a1', 7]])
```

This array has 2 columns

What I want to do is create an array with 2 columns. Column 1 should have 'a1' , 'a2', 'a3' values in its' rows and column 2 should have summation of those corresponding values.

```
new_gona = array([['a1', 10], ['a2', 5], ['a3', 4]])
```

Here, corresponding values are taken as follows.

```
'a1' : 3 + 7 = 10
'a2' : 5 
'a3' : 1 + 2 + 1 = 4
```

What would be an easy method to achieve this?

Comment: I remember seeing an efficient solution with Pandas the last time this problem came up, but I don't remember what it was. Maybe someone with better search skills can find it.

Comment: Note: Running the code you've posted produces an array of dtype `'|S2'`. This means that the integers are stored as strings, instead of as `int32` or some other reasonable dtype. That may be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict 
from operator import itemgetter

sums = defaultdict(int)
for key, value in gona:
    sums[key] += value

new_gona = sorted(sums.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(0))
```

Cheat?

Answer (score 3):

Use pandas and its indexing magic:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

gona = np.array([['a1', 3], ['a2', 5], ['a3', 1], 
              ['a3', 2], ['a3', 1], ['a1', 7]])

# Create series where second items are data and first items are index
series = pd.Series(gona[:,1],gona[:,0],dtype=np.float)

# Compute sums across index
sums = series.sum(level=0)

# Construct new array in the format you want
new_gona = np.array(zip(sums.index,sums.values))

new_gona
# out[]:
# array([['a1', '10.0'],
#        ['a2', '5.0'],
#        ['a3', '4.0']], 
#       dtype='|S4')
```

It's also notable that `np.array`s can only hold one datatype. So your mixing of strings and numeric types needs to be corrected for by specifying `dtype=np.float`. You can use `np.int` if you want.

Answer (score 2):

A numpy only solution:

```
>>> labels, indices = np.unique(gona[:, 0], return_inverse=True)
>>> sums = np.bincount(indices, weights=gona[:, 1].astype(np.float))
>>> new_gona = np.column_stack((labels, sums))
>>> new_gona
array([['a1', '10'],
       ['a2', '5.'],
       ['a3', '4.']], 
      dtype='|S2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Then, the list comprehension will do it pretty easy:

```
def fst(x): return x[0]
[(a, sum([int(m[1]) for m in gona if a == m[0]])) for a in set(map(fst, gona)) ]
```

This is basic Python. No libraries involved. The first function is defined only avoid the lambda expression in the `map` at the end. Both the Pandas and the NumPy solutions already mentioned seem pretty interesting though. +1 for both!

Answer (score -2):

you have to write a loop around gona and store the (a1) as a key in dictionary object. The value should be added ofcourse

Comment: comments please, a solution was asked which was provided. No code but logical explanation